# How to animate an image to move in a circle in a-frame?

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, webvr

I have been trying to move an image in a perfect circle but not able to do that perfectly. I have coded a box to revolve in a square path. The code is below.

```html
<a-box id="box" position="-1 0.5 -3" src="images/pic2.jpg" onclick="loaddoc()" visible="true">
            <a-animation attribute="position" fill="both" from="-1.0 0.5 -3" to="-2 0.5 -3" dur="5000"></a-animation>
            <a-animation attribute="position" fill="both" from="-2 0.5 -3" to="-2 0.5 3" dur="5000" delay="5000"></a-animation>
            <a-animation attribute="position" fill="both" from="-2.0 0.5 3" to="-1 0.5 3" dur="5000" delay="10000"></a-animation>
            <a-animation attribute="position" fill="both" from="-1.0 0.5 3" to="-1 0.5 -3" dur="5000" delay="15000"></a-animation>
        </a-box>
```

Comment: Post js-fiddle of your code.

Answer (score 4):

It's all about parent - child relativeness.
You place a child with an position offset in Your parent entity, and rotate the parent.

---

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity position="0 5 -5">
    <a-box color="red" position="0 -1 0"></a-box>
    <a-animation attribute="rotation" dur="4000" fill="forwards" to="0 0 360" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach your image to a given entity and rotate that entity. Position your image such that the distance from the center of the parent entity is the desired radius of orbit. Here is an example straight from the documentation:

Say I want to to rotate a fictional green moon around an axis.

Create the moon:

```
<a-sphere position="5 0 0" color="mediumseagreen"></a-sphere>
```

Then wrap it in an invisible plane and **rotate the plane**:

```
<a-entity rotation="0 0 0" animation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: true; dur: 10000">
  <a-sphere position="5 0 0" color="mediumseagreen"></a-sphere>
</a-entity>
```

The **orbital radius** of my moon is **5 units around the x-axis** as noted by the position of my sphere "5 0 0". To increase the orbital radius, increase the position to the desire value along the desired axes.

**To accomplish the same feat with your image your code should be something along these lines:**

```
<a-entity position="-1 0.5 0"rotation="0 0 0" animation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: true; dur: 20000">
  <a-box id="box" position="0 0 3" material="src: images/pic2.jpg; visible: true;"></a-box>
</a-entity>
```